# Is it wrong to get a scope of an object and call its functions?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a service that creates a popup and spawns it, but i need a way to subscribe on close event and have a way to close it from the outside.

Is it wrong if a Spawner service returns popup element (or it's scope) so I could close the popup and subscribe to closed event through a controller?

**UPDATE** (answer thanks to @Brett's video)

It seems that the right pattern would be creating a **Service that spawns** the popup on demand, but it **returns a proxy object** that has properties *open* etc.

A controller that requested spawning a popup has to listen on proxy changes and decide what to do on such events.

This solutions fits the video if I am right.

Comment: Why is your pop-up a service and not a directive? You can expose a public API with a directive since you can configure it to have its own controller.

Comment: How do I spawn a popup then? I was thinking that it would be nice to have a service that spawns a popup with given content.

Comment: question is pretty vague. Please try something and bring back real code and a demo if you have problems

Comment: Actually I think the question is fine - this is one of those things you should ask/think about **before** writing code that doesn't work, and it's one of the more counter intuitive bits of angularjs - especially when beginner tutorials hammer home that **DOM manipulation should only happen in directives**, which is not necessarily always the case.

Comment: After your edit, I want to re-iterate that there is no *right* way to do this. However, forcing a controller to listen for changes on an object is not particularly neat in my opinion - I think returning a promise from the controller is both more efficient, and easier to read.

Comment: Who should listen to the model changes then?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's *"wrong"*, but it does sound a bit hacky.

The way I would design this is to have your service expose methods so you can do something like the following:

```
.controller( 'SomeController', function (Popup) {
  Popup.spawn({
    // options here
  })
  .then( function (result) {
    // on-close code
  })
  .catch( function (cancelReason) {
    // on cancel code (if you have 2 buttons)
  });
  // assuming you are using 'controllerAs' syntax, you can then
  // access this through the DOM.
  this.closePopup = Popup.close
);
```

So, how would you acheive this?

- The Popup should maintain a reference to its element
- The Popup service's `spawn` method should fill the element and make it visible, but it should return a promise, not the element itself.
- Clicking the close button on the popup should empty/remove the element, then resolve that promise
- The `close` method used by the close button should also be accessible to a calling controller through the service.

#### Service or directive?

Prompted by a comment on the question, you need *at least* a service (because they are injectable into controllers etc), but you could also use a directive instead of just manipulating an element through the service.

The way I have done it in the past is to have a **directive** to control the DOM manipulation, which has a `$scope.$watch` set up to watch a property on a complimentary **service** which makes the directive visible or invisible, but there's actually no reason you can't exclusively use a service if you prefer that approach.

Comment: The strategy described in this [video](http://youtu.be/AIO2Om7B83s?t=15m1s) from ng-eurpoe 2014 is what I would suggest - which is somewhat similar to what you're explaining I guess.

Comment: Thanks @Brett for the video, you've helped even your first comment is misleading.

Comment: You're welcome @mkostelac. Sorry for being misleading, but it's a question I haven't fully wrapped my head around either, which is why I asked.